# The paste command is outputing tabs instead of new lines when used with process substitution

Tags: bash, tr, paste

The first command below produces each number on a separate line, and I would expect the second command to do the same thing because the only difference between the two is that we are using `echo '1 2 3'` and `echo {1..3}` (both of which produce the same output). **But, the second command produces the numbers that are separated by tabs instead of new lines. Why?**

Furthermore, notice that the only difference between the second and the third commands is that we are passing the result to `paste` via process substitution, but without that, it shows the expected result, which could imply that it is a `paste` related issue, but I don't quite see what the issue is.

```bash
§ paste <(echo '1 2 3' | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n')
1
2
3

§ paste <(echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n')
1   2   3


§ echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n'
1
2
3
```

I tried to see the output produced at the end of the process substitution pipeline to see what was being output, and it does indeed appear to be the same.

```bash
§ paste <(echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n' | tee /dev/stderr) > /dev/null 
1
2
3

§ paste <(echo '1 2 3' | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n' | tee /dev/stderr) > /dev/null 
1
2
3
```

---

If it matters, here are the versions of the tools:

```bash
§ which tr paste
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/tr
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/paste
```

```bash
§ tr --version
tr (GNU coreutils) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.

Written by Jim Meyering.
```

```bash
§ paste --version
paste (GNU coreutils) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.

Written by David M. Ihnat and David MacKenzie.
```

```bash
§ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

```bash
§ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.7.10
BuildVersion:   20G1427
```

I am on macOS, but use GNU utils installed via `brew`.

---

Addition debug information requested by comments with `set -x` active:

```bash
§ paste <(echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n')
+ paste /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 /dev/fd/61
++ echo 1
++ echo 3
++ tr ' ' '\t'
++ tr ' ' '\t'
++ tr '\t' '\n'
++ tr '\t' '\n'
++ echo 2
++ tr ' ' '\t'
++ tr '\t' '\n'
1   2   3
```

```bash
§ paste <(echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\n')
+ paste /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 /dev/fd/61
++ echo 1
++ tr ' ' '\n'
++ echo 2
++ echo 3
++ tr ' ' '\n'
++ tr ' ' '\n'
1   2   3
```

```bash
§ echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\n' | paste
+ tr ' ' '\n'
+ echo 1 2 3
+ paste
1
2
3
```

And `hexdump` output:

```bash
§ paste <(echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\n') | hexdump -C
00000000  31 09 32 09 33 0a                                 |1.2.3.|
00000006
```

```bash
§ echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\n' | paste | hexdump -C
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 33 0a                                 |1.2.3.|
00000006
```

Comment: Using single quotes inhibits special character interpretation. Instead, use `"\t"` and `"\n"`.

Comment: @waltinator - I am not sure, I follow. The first example clearly shows that `tr` is able to interpret the special characters. I do not intend for the shell to do the interpolation, but even with double quotes, it makes no difference, i.e.,  `paste <(echo {1..3} | tr " " "\t" | tr "\t" "\n")` produces a tab-separated list like the second command.

Comment: @waltinator -If it helps, `echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n' | paste` produces the correct output too. So, piping to `paste` works fine, but using `paste` with process substitution seemingly interprets the lines as columns (?). But, why?

Comment: Ignore waltinator’s comment, it’s not relevant here. FWIW I get the expected behaviour with `{1..3}` but I’m not using macOS.

Comment: @waltinator no they don't. The shell doesn't interpret `'\t'` and `"\t"` differently, both just mean a literal `\ ` followed by a literal `t`. You would need `$'\t'` for the shell to interpret that as a tab. For `tr`, single and double quotes make no difference. Compare `echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\t'` with `echo {1..3} | tr ' ' \\t` or `echo {1..3} | tr ' ' "\t"` and you will see all three produce the same output.

Comment: This is very strange. Like Stephen, I cannot reproduce this on my Arch machine nor on an Ubuntu server I have access to. Can you show us the output of `set -x; paste <(echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\t' | tr '\t' '\n')` and then also (still with `set -x` active) `paste <(echo {1..3} | tr ' ' '\n')`?

Comment: @terdon - I added the requested and some additional information.